# Use Idea+Gradle can't import aspectjrt and aspectweaver jar

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle, aspectj

I was learning Spring AOP ,and i write a sample use Spring AOP's Around Advice.It need the aspectjrt.jar and aspectjweaver.jar.so i add dependencies in the build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {

   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.6.RELEASE'
   compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.9'
   compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.8.9'
}
```

Refresh the gradle,but the *External Libraries* didn't have aspectjrt.jar and aspectweaver.jar. 
Then I found this information from the file *.idea/Libraries/Gradle_org_aspectj_aspectjrt_1.8.9.xml*

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.9">
  <CLASSES>
     <root url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/Could not resolve org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.9." />
   </CLASSES>
  <JAVADOC />
  <SOURCES />
 </library>
</component>
```

but i can find the jar from there: * ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.9/87372d9e2323313bec24b09a325bfea8ae0eb867/aspectjrt.jar*, and if i use the string * ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.9/87372d9e2323313bec24b09a325bfea8ae0eb867/aspectjrt.jar!/* replace the url's value in this sentence :.it will be ok .But If changing the build.gradle again, it will return back.

Can some help me ? THX!

- macOS 10.12.3
- IDEA 2016.3.4
- Gradle 3.1
- jdk 1.8.0_121-b13

Comment: What repositories did you define?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the build.gradle file like this,It's work! Amazing.

```
dependencies {

   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
   compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.9'
   compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.8.9'
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.6.RELEASE'
}
```